# How to change helm styling with font-face?

Tags: emacs, emacs-helm

I trying to change helm-source-header style with code below:

```
    (set-face-attribute 'helm-source-header nil
                        :background "gray30"
                        :height 90)
```

After Emacs initialization i have an error:

*error: Invalid face, helm-source-header*

But if I run this code after initialization changes applying to helm without problems.

I guess that I should run this code after helm init, but how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
  (eval-after-load 'helm
    (lambda () 
      (set-face-attribute 'helm-source-header nil
                          :background "gray30"
                          :height 90)))
```

(Looks not bad with `zenburn-theme` by the way, thanks for the idea!)